# Painting relative to scrollbars

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, gdi+, pascal

I am making some components for my own use, i am trying to make a "riff generator" for making tunes in midi format. Therefore i am writing a pianoroll editor (like in fl studio etc).

[image: Screenshot of component]

The problem im having is drawing relative to the scrollbar positions. I am trying it for two days now, but i cant seem to figure out how to do this. I already added variables and procedures for setting the scroll positions, but i dont understand how i can draw up/down and sideways when i scroll.

I added the code i have so far, i am using the GDI+ unit from Erik Bilsen ([www.bilsen.com/gdiplus](http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus)) for drawing.

If anyone can look at my code, and help me to get the drawing right that would be awesome! I will release this and other components as opensource when i finish, so other people will be able to use these components too.

The component code: https://pastebin.com/562yfDvu

```
FScrollPosX : Integer;
FScrollPosY : Integer;
FScrollMaxX : Integer;
FScrollMaxY : Integer;
FOldScrollX : Integer;
FOldScrollY : Integer;
```

Comment: You only need to subtract. Typically, I have a variable `FScrollPos: TPoint` which contains the coordinates of the top-left on-screen pixel in the coordinate system of the content. So if `FScrollPos = Point(10, 20)`, the user has scrolled `10` px to the right and `20` px down. To convert between content and on-screen coordinates, just subtract.

Comment: Yes i already have a FScrollPosX and a FScrollPosY but if i substract i get all kind of weird drawing, maybe you can look at my code and see what im doing wrong - im trying it for two days now.. and i dont see where it goes wrong..

Comment: Why not try to create a very simple GUI control (like one painting a 1000×2000 px fixed-size triangle) just to learn how to make scrollbars and scrolling work, and then try to apply the same technique to your piano-roll control? If you have trouble making that work, at least you have a manageable amount of code suitable for a SO question.

Comment: Yes i already worked with scrollbars, i made some listboxes and some other things, where i can make it work without any problem - but when i try it in this component it doesnt draw like it should/how i want it - so i know somewhere im doing something wrong.. but i cant seem to figure out where exactly

Comment: So doesn't provide this service. It's not here to debug your code. We can help with specific questions about code that is posted in this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some typical calculations**

*Scrollbar range*

```
Given Virtual extent (VirtExt) in pixels
Given Viewport extent (VPExt) in pixels

Scrollbar range = VirtExt - VPExt (to leave the last part visible in the viewport)
```

*Object position in ViewPort with a given scroll position*

```
Given Object.pos (ObjPos) (in virtual space)
Given Sroll position (ScrPos)

Position in viewport: ObjPos - ScrPos
```

*Object visibility filter*

```
Visible if (OPos >= ScrPos) and (OPos < ScrPos+VPExt)
```